# How to create an instance of a contract in Truffle that deployed by another Ethereum node?

Tags: truffle, contract-invocation, private-blockchain, truffle-migration

I set Truffle to my private network. Now, I need to interact to a contract (C1) that deployed by another node of this network and I need to do that by Truffle. As I understood, I should define C1 to Truffle so that Truffle knows C1 deployed before. Because when I try this command on Truffle console:

```
C1.deployed().then(fucntion(ins){c1=ins})
```

This error throwed:

```
Error: C1 has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

After some search, I tried these commands on Truffle console:

```
truffle(PrivEth)> const c1=await artifacts.require("C1")

truffle(PrivEth)> const C1=await c1.at('0x42C564EF81c9DF9338a62c13056FFEc84285a3DC')
```

But this error throwed:

```
Uncaught:
Error: Cannot create instance of C1; no code at address 0x42C564EF81c9DF9338a62c13056FFEc84285a3DC
```

This error throwed while C1 deployed on that address by another Ethereum node from the network. I don't know why Truffle cannot see C1 code at the address. Do I miss anything on console?
I don't know am I trying the commands by a correct way or not? Please provide the correct way, Thanks.

This is the Truffle config:

```
const Web3=require("web3");
module.exports = {
      networks: {
          development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
     },
     develop:{
      port:8545
     },
     PrivEth:{
      provider:function(){
        return new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://<ip>:8551");
      },
      network_id:"1111"
     }
 },
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.0",
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is. When I wanted to connect Truffle console to `PrivEth` network I tried this:

`truffle develop --network PrivEth`

This caused C1 not be deployed into `PrivEth`. BTW, the C1's address was unknown for all other Ethereum nodes.

I changed the above command to:

`truffle console --network PrivEth`

And the issue resolved!